# Flutter build failed with fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found

Tags: flutter

I am developing the app with flutter,

I am getting  fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found , this error when I build my app.

I tried reinstall cocoapod and delete podfile.lock and reinstalled it,

but I am still getting this error..

what can I do for this error ?

```
daegilpyo@DAEGILs-MacBook-Pro eminail % flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.4, on macOS 11.0.1 20B50 darwin-x64, locale en-CA)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.2)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
daegilpyo@DAEGILs-MacBook-Pro eminail % 





 vent sent after app closed: {id: 0, progressId: null, finished: true}
    Launching lib/main.dart on DAEGIL의 iPhone in debug mode...
    lib/main.dart:1
    Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: T6ULPGT4J7
    Xcode build done.                                           18.9s
    Failed to build iOS app
    Error output from Xcode build:
    ↳
        ** BUILD FAILED **
    Xcode's output:
    ↳
        Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
        In file included from /Users/daegilpyo/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher-5.7.10/ios/Classes/FLTURLLauncherPlugin.m:7:
        /Users/daegilpyo/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher-5.7.10/ios/Classes/FLTURLLauncherPlugin.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
        #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        1 error generated.
        Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
        Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
        Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
        Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
        note: Using new build system
        note: Building targets in parallel
        note: Planning build
        note: Constructing build description
```

Comment: If I make new project and run it , it works fine...

Answer (score -1):

go to terminal, backup your ios/Runner folder and delete your ios folder. Then go to terminal and execute

```
cd path/to/your/project/projectName
flutter create .
flutter run
```

if flutter run fails

```
cd ios
pod install
cd ..
flutter run
```

Comment: so you are suggesting to create a new flutter project and import all new data inside it?

Comment: or kind of refreshing the project files, it won't recreate or overwrite to already present files